# jquery mobile does not get the right url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, click

whenever a button click event is created, I take the data-url attribute of the button and do change the page to that URL. the problem is the page loads twice and the url is not right, but it displays the current page + #panel-responsive-page1 (div id, i dont know where it is coming from).

This is my javascript. What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery( ".button" ).on( "vclick", function( ) {
            $.mobile.changePage( $(this).attr('data-url'), { transition: "slideup"} );
        });
```

and this is how the button is created:

```
<button type="button" data-url="'.$button['data_url'].'" class="button data-theme-a"'.$button_class.'  >' . $button['name'] . '</button>
```

I have tried using the change event too, and the problem persists.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
data-url="'.$button['data_url'].'"
```

to:

```
data-url="'.$button["data_url"].'"
```

Comment: its not that, because the button recieves the data-url attribute and when I check in Network, the corresponding url gives positive response, but it loads twice and the url does not change to what it should be, but comes like this: http://localhost/.../item.php#panel-responsive-page1 though the page appears (javascripts don't work of course)

Comment: I found another way, I changed the button to anchor: <a type="button" href="'.$button["data_url"].'" class="'.$button_class.'"  >' . $button['name'] . '</a> And it works fine but I will have to fix the style of the buttons.

Comment: Glad you found a solution by yourself :)